# How to add different lines in different facets in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

Suppose I have four plots after I faceted my main plot. I want to draw a vertical line on x = 1 in first facet, x = 2 in second facet, x = 3 in third facet and x = 4 in forth facet. How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44196384/how-to-produce-different-geom-vline-in-different-facets-in-r

Comment: library(tidyverse)

dataLine <- mpg %>%
  group_by(trans) %>%
  summarize(mean_x = mean(cty))

ggplot(mpg) +
  aes(x = cty, y = hwy) +
  facet_wrap(facets = vars(trans)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_vline(data  = dataLine, aes(xintercept = mean_x, colour = trans))